# Changing Logging Level of OWasp CSRFGuard

Tags: csrf, owasp

I have successfully installed [OWasp CSRFGuard](https://owasp.org/www-project-csrfguard/) in my Java Application.

My `CSRFGuard.Properties` file contains the following:

```
# Logger
#
# The logger property (org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger) defines the qualified class name of 
# the object responsible for processing all log messages produced by CSRFGuard. The default
# CSRFGuard logger is org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger. This class logs all messages
# to System.out which JavaEE application servers redirect to a vendor specific log file.
# Developers can customize the logging behavior of CSRFGuard by implementing the
# org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ILogger interface and setting the logger property to the new
# logger's qualified class name. The following configuration snippet instructs OWASP CSRFGuard
# to capture all log messages to the console:
#
# org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ConsoleLogger
 org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger
```

I can see the different logging levels from https://www.javatips.net/api/OWASP-CSRFGuard-master/csrfguard/src/main/java/org/owasp/csrfguard/log/JavaLogger.java

```
   LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        break;
    case Debug:
        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        break;
    case Info:
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        break;
    case Warning:
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        break;
    case Error:
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
        break;
    case Fatal:
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE
```

How can I change the logging level in `CSRFGuard.Properties` to show only `Level.WARNING` 
At the moment, every request is analyzed and logged.

```
INFO: CsrfGuard analyzing request example.com/examplepage.jsp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the following line in `CSRFGuard.Properties`

```
 org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger
```

with

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.Logger=com.myPackage.MyLogger
```

And add a new class as below (based on [this code](https://www.javatips.net/api/OWASP-CSRFGuard-master/csrfguard/src/main/java/org/owasp/csrfguard/log/JavaLogger.java)), setting your required log level in the `MyLogger()` constructor (in the example below I set the minimum log level to `Level.WARNING`)

```
package com.myPackage

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.owasp.csrfguard.log.LogLevel;

public class MyLogger implements org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ILogger {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Owasp.CsrfGuard");
    
    public MyLogger() {
        LOGGER.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void log(String msg) {
        LOGGER.info(msg.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", ""));
    }

    @Override
    public void log(LogLevel level, String msg) {
        // Remove CR and LF characters to prevent CRLF injection
        String sanitizedMsg = msg.replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "");
        
        switch(level) {
            case Trace:
                LOGGER.finest(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            case Debug:
                LOGGER.fine(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            case Info:
                LOGGER.info(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            case Warning:
                LOGGER.warning(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            case Error:
                LOGGER.warning(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            case Fatal:
                LOGGER.severe(sanitizedMsg);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("unsupported log level " + level);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void log(Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void log(LogLevel level, Exception exception) {
            switch(level) {
            case Trace:
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINEST, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            case Debug:
                LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            case Info:
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            case Warning:
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            case Error:
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            case Fatal:
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, exception.getLocalizedMessage(), exception);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("unsupported log level " + level);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems that org.owasp.csrfguard.log.ILogger is not available anymore in 4.3.0 is there any replacement?

Comment: It seems from https://github.com/OWASP/www-project-csrfguard/pull/33/files#diff-b7fa28b55b2c023d583a79f5d989c823c0b73ab94f10a7ce7693a1bbe53fc6a9 that iLogger was deleted and replaced by SLF4J #30